# Cloudflare R2 403 on redirect from express JS

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-r2

When a user asks for a resource, I redirect them to that resource on cloudflare R2. R2 bucket is behind my own DNS (if that can help or I can change something there).

The issue I am facing is a 403 Forbidden on the preflight. "Request method: OPTIONS".

did anyone face this issue here ? how can I fix it ?

I tried changing the headers on the DNS level to allow everything, but still can't figure it out.

Comment: Did you find a solution?